# ASP.Net MVC Refresh other element in another view after ajax post

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a 2 partial views, both may be on the same page at one time, but not always.

What is the most efficient way to refresh an element in one of the views after the other posts back via jQuery ajax?

I don't want dependencies between one part of the page and the other.

Comment: I don't know if I udnerstood but you can call .Load method passing an url of an action that returns a partialView and add this result to a div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fire an event after an ajax load is complete.  Of course, you'll have to bind a container or the element in question to the event so it will update when the event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

In the jquery .ajax onsuccess handler fire another ajax call to update the second screen area. This keeps the completely independent.

Answer (score 0):

Mantorok
if you are making an ajax call then there will be a success function. Just add the follwing code given below.

```
location.reload(true);
```

hope it will work...